# While loop not working (python)

Tags: python, batch-file

I decided i wanted to automate the solving of a math riddle, however, it doesn't work in python although, i've successfully done it in batch:

```
@echo off
set people=1
set handshakes=0
set cnt=0
:LOOP
set /A people+=1
set /A cnt+=1
set /A handshakes+=%cnt%
echo.handshakes:%handshakes%,people=%people%
if "%handshakes%" NEQ "66" Goto :LOOP
echo.---------Final Result------------
echo.Handshakes:%handshakes%
echo.People:%people%
pause > nul
exit /b
```

But the following python code for a very odd reason does not work:

```
people = 1
handshakes = 0
cnt = 0
while a < 66:
    people+=1
    cnt+=1
    handshakes+=cnt
print (handshakes)
print (people)
raw_input()
```

The riddle:
At a party, everyone shook hands with everybody else. There were 66 handshakes. How many people were at the party?

Comment: When you ask a question, never say "does not work". Always explain how the program fails. Provide exact error messages.

Comment: Dos not work, is a bit unspecific. Do you get 42, an error or does it explode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop checks a variable named `a`. However, you never assign to `a` nor modify it inside the loop.

Comment: LOL, thanks. Lack of sleep here.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, your exit condition is `a < 66`, but you do not have a variable named `a` anywhere in your program.  Change this to `handshakes < 66`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define `a` and you never update `a` within the while loop, plus the `raw_input` isn't really doing something.